# Hiding monitor from windows, working with it from my app only

Tags: windows, hardware, display

I need to use a monitor as a "private" device for my special application, I want to use it as a flashlight of a sort and draw special patterns on it in full screen. I don't want this monitor to be recognized by OS (Windows 7) as a monitor. I.e. user should not be able to move mouse to that monitor, or change its resolution, or run screensaver on it or whatever. But I want to be able to interact with it from my application. Monitor is plugged using an HDMI cable to a video card (most probably nVidia).

What is the simplest way to do this? All solutions are appreciated, including purchasing additional adapters or simple video cards, or any other special devices.

Answer (score 3):

That is an obviously impossible request, since the requirements are diametrically opposed.

In order for any "application" (which of necessity *runs on the OS*) to use or recognize the monitor,  the monitor has to be known to, and driven by, the OS.

In fact, for any modern OS, there is no way to access the hardware without going through the OS itself.

What you might investigate is the ability of a full hardware hypervisor, such as vmware ESXi, to expose that second display ***only*** to a dedicated VM, on which you can then run your application.

Comment: I don't really want OS to not to recognize the monitor, I want the monitor to be hidden from a user as an output device. It's not obvious for me that it is impossible.